# BIRT Reports method calling multiple times

Tags: report, birt

In BIRT Reports according to my requirement I need to take tables for same dataset if I drag the field in seconds table method calling multiple times how can I resolve this issue.can you please give me idea

Answer (score 0):

You could use a report variable as a flag to remember if the method was already called. Then, at the beginning of the methode, test if the variable is already true. If yes, skip the code. Otherwise, set the flag and execute the code.
By the way: Note that BIRT caches dataset results.
If you use the same DS with the same parameter values multiple times, then only at the first time will the records will be actually fetched from the database.